# Formula to ignore hidden columns

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count visible columns in a spreadsheet with no luck. I've been trying using `SUBTOTAL` function but it's applied to hidden/visible rows only. I also tried working with `CELL("width")` function, but it doesn't return 0 when a cell is hidden

Is there any other option to ignore hidden columns in a count formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely create your own custom function using Google Apps Script.

For example, the following function counts the number of visible columns in your active sheet:

```
function countVisibleColumns() {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var n_cols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
var hidden_cols = []
var cnt = 0;
  
for (var i=1; i<=n_cols ; i++) {
  if ( sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i) ){
  continue;}
  else {cnt +=1} }
Logger.log(cnt)
return cnt;
}
```

You just need to click on **Tools => Script editor** and then copy the aforementioned code into a blank script. Then you can directly use the function as a formula in the google sheet like `=countVisibleColumns()`.
See screenshot attached for more information.

[image: Implementation of the code]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Marios! Is there any way to make this custom function recalculate on hide/unhide event and apply to a specific range? Basically, I need to have some kind of an 'indicator' of a hidden column to ignore it in "IF" formula - similar to 'SUBTOTAL' function for rows

Comment: Unfortunately, hide/unhide is not considered an event. But you can trigger the function let's say every time you edit a cell. Via script again you can apply a second function to calculate for example SUM or anything you want only for the visible columns. But what do you want to calculate? What function would you like to use for the visible columns? Edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, Marios! I posted a new question with a sample sheet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241198/google-function-to-apply-to-visible-rows-only